# Amazon VPC NACL default rules evaluation order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

With my understanding, NACL (Network Access Control List) is the subnet firewall.

I'm  trying to understand what are the defaults when creating a NACL:

- Rule #100 - all ports from all IPs are allowed by default, otherwise
- All is denied

So, bottom line, is all allowed or denied? I know that according to AWS best practices, all access should be disabled by default.

[image: Rules]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The rules are evaluated in number order.

As soon as the traffic matches the rule, the Allow/Deny is applied and evaluation ends.

Therefore, the default rule that you show above **Allows all traffic**. Nothing falls through to the default rule.

This numbered logic is handy for something like this, that denies ICMP traffic, then allows everything else:

[image: NACL rules]

Here's one that uses the default rule to only allow HTTPS:

[image: NACL rule]